# How i can use a criteria in cicle for i

Tags: vba, loops, excel

i want to use a criteria in my loop
but not work

```
UR = 3
ReDim arng(UR, 3) As Variant
For X = 0 To UR
    arng(X, 0) = ConvDate(Cells(X , 8))
    arng(X, 1) = ConvDate(Cells(X , 12))
    arng(X, 2) = Iif(Cells(X , 12) = "", MsgBox("empty"), MsgBox("Full")) 
Next X
```

even if the cell(X,12) is actually empty both messages show
Why?!?!?

isn't possible to use a criteria??
thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked over a lil bit, try this

```
dim UR as integer
UR = 3
ReDim arng(UR, 3) As Variant

For X = 0 To UR
arng(X, 0) = ConvDate(Cells(X , 8))
arng(X, 1) = ConvDate(Cells(X , 12))

if Cells(X , 12) = "" then
  MsgBox("empty")

else
  msgbox("full")

end if 

Next X
```

Comment: no problem, if that solved the problem please mark as an answer:)